# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с проблемой. Решил поменять способ замены фрагмента на этот:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    binding.frameContainer.removeAllViews();
    binding.frameContainer.addView(fragment.getView());
}
```

Раньше у меня был такой:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(binding.frameContainer.getId(), fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Но возникает ошибка java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup at .MainActivity.loadFragment(MainActivity.java:241)

Как можно ее решить? Перепробовал многое.. И ViewBinding отключал фрагмента, и пробовал другие решения. не помогает.

Мой onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentGameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fragment.getView()` возвращает не `null` после вызова `onCreateView` метода и до вызова `onDestroyView` метода.

Эти методы будут вызваны системой, когда вы фрагмент отобразите через `FragmentManager`.

Вы же пытаетесь ещё не загруженную разметку извлечённую из фрагмента отобразить. Скорее всего, даже если бы метод `onCreateView` фрагмента был бы вызван вы словили бы ошибку попытки добавления вьюхи у которой уже есть родитель.

В общем - вы пытаетесь зачем-то использовать фрагменты так, как их использовать не надо. Просто верните старый код использования оных.

Comment: Мне так посоветовал человек, у которого это работает. Я был сам удивлен, но ведь это же работает)
может есть какой то секрет в API, неизвестно.

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper попросите этого человека целиком код показать - очень интересно как оно работает)

Comment: я смотрел весь код. у него просто new Fragment.

Comment: Крайне странно. Может там где-то вручную вызываются методы жизненного цикла?